# hbase: assign CompareFilter.CompareOp based on input value

Tags: java, hbase

Can we take the compareOperator value based on input value? For example if my input is *eq*, then it should pick  `CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL`, else if input is *ne* it should pick `CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL`.

Something like

```
if(input.equals("eq")) {
    myCompareOp = EQUAL;
}else if(input.equals("ne")) {
    myCompareOp = NOT_EQUAL;
}

SingleColumnValueFilter colValFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(<CF>), Bytes.toBytes(<CQ>)
                , myCompareOp, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(<value>)));
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on above code , Yes it will work. Below is the example code snippet, you can have a look as well.where `ConditionType`  is enum... like this you can also prepare your own enum(not mandatory if condition is also fine)

```
private Filter buildSimpleQuery(ConditionType ct, String name, Object value) {
    name = super.getRealPropertyName(name);
    validatePropertyValue(name, value);
    Class<?> clazz = getPrimitiveFieldClass(name, value.getClass());
    CompareOp compareOp = null;
    boolean regexCompRequired = false;
    switch (ct) {
    case EQUALS:
        compareOp = CompareOp.EQUAL;
        regexCompRequired = String.class == clazz && value.toString().endsWith("*");
        break;
    case NOT_EQUALS:
        compareOp = CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL;
        regexCompRequired = String.class == clazz && value.toString().endsWith("*");
        break;
    case GREATER_THAN:
        compareOp = CompareOp.GREATER;
        break;
    case GREATER_OR_EQUALS:
        compareOp = CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL;
        break;
    case LESS_THAN:
        compareOp = CompareOp.LESS;
        break;
    case LESS_OR_EQUALS:
        compareOp = CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL;
        break;
    default: 
        break;
    }
    String qualifier = name;
    String theFamily = family != null ? family : familyMap.get(qualifier);
    ByteArrayComparable byteArrayComparable = regexCompRequired 
        ? new RegexStringComparator(value.toString().replace("*", "."))
        : new BinaryComparator(value.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Filter query = new SingleColumnValueFilter(theFamily.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                                               qualifier.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                                               compareOp,
                                               byteArrayComparable);
    return query;
}
```